# Debian V4L2 composite video USB capturer

Tags: linux, video-capture

Im trying to capture composite from [this camera sensor](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00JP4SZ7M?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00) with [this capturer device](http://www.amazon.co.uk/367/dp/B008F0SARC) that according to [this is compatible with linux](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/OTG102#Live_Viewing)

I know the is no harware problem becuase if tried from my windows machin and there if video feed coming to my computer, when I try on linux tho it doesnt work, I get a green screen when capturing, I dont know if I'm using the right colour encoding or what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried with mplayer, vlc, qv4l2 and guvcview with the same result on all of them. Green screen.

I'm running debian 8.2.0 kernel 3.16.0-4 everything looks good, lsusb is returning what expected, dmesg also return what expect.

Anyone has any experience with this devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using VMware for this, turns out the VMWARE toold for the USB where not supporting the camera correctly, spinned up on a Rpi and worked fine,